# How does $\frac{1}{2^n-1}+\frac{2^n-2}{2^n-1}\left(\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$??

Tags: probability, combinatorics

No matter what I try I cannot simplify it. However, even symbolab and wolfram alpha do not simplify this. Is it just me or is the question faulty? It comes from this:

Eight players play in the quarter-finals at Wimbledon. The winner of the quarter-finals plays again in the semi-final to decide who enters the finals.

a) Assume all 8 players have an equally likely chance of winning. Show that the probability that baby two players winning is $\frac{1}{4}$

b) What is the probability that two particular people will play each other if the tournament begins with 16 players?

c) What is the probability if the tournament starts with $2^n$ players?

The worked solutions provided for parts a) and b) are $\frac{1}{7}+\frac{6}{7}(\frac{1}{2})^3 = \frac{1}{4}$. I understand the $\frac{1}{7}+\frac{6}{7}$ but not the half, and especially to the power of 3???

Similarly for b) $\frac{1}{15}+\frac{14}{15}(\frac{1}{4})^2 = \frac{1}{8}$. This is even more confusing! Why is it to the power of 2 now, and why is it not a half but a quarter?

For part c),it is easy to reason the formula $\frac{1}{2^n-1}+\frac{2^n-2}{2^n-1}\left(\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}\right)^2$ (or at least the part excluding the brakets). I do not understand how the part inteh brackets is derived and simplified (as per the title)

Comment: The equality in  the title is false.

Comment: Re @KaviRamaMurthy 's cmment try $n=2$ we get $1=1/2$ absurd!

Comment: Ahhh ok I thought it was jsut my poor algebra. How would you do part c) then? What would replace the part in the bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let us evolve a simple way of computing the probability of any **particular** pair meeting in an $2^n$ player knockout tournament.

It should be obvious that there will be a total of $(2^n-1)$ matches (because in each match one player loses, and $(2^n-1)$ players must lose)

Also, number of pairs possible $= \dbinom{2^n}{2}$,

Thus required probability $=\dfrac{2^n-1}{\dbinom{2^n}{2}}$, which simplifies to $\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}$

So far as the title is concerned, there is obviously
some typographical error. The answers tally, I'll try to figure out the logic used, but idk why such a tortuous method needs to be used at all !

---

**Added explanation re book formula:**

We know that in any round, the number of players is in the form $2^n$ and the *Pr* of a particular pair meeting is $\frac 1 {2^n-1}$

Let $2^n = x$, and assuming they have not met in this round, then for them to meet in the next round, we need
P(not meet in this round)$\times$ P(both win this round) $\times$P(meet in next round)

$=  (1 - \frac 1 {x-1})\cdot\frac 1 4 \cdot\frac 1 {\frac {x}2-1}$ which simplifies to $\frac 1 {2(x-1)}$

**ie half the probability of this round**

Thus the formula for a tournament of $2^n$ people will be

$\left(\frac 1 {2^n -1}\right)\left(1 + \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 4 +.. \;to\; 
 n\; terms\right)$ = $\frac {1 }{2^n-1}\cdot  \frac{2(2^n-1)}{2^n} = \frac 1 {2^{n-1}}$

**PS**

It is simpler to eliminate all exponents and GP etc, by instead solving for a $K$ player tournament, knowing that in a normal tournament $K$ is in the form $2^n$, then the indicated probability is simply $\frac{K-1}{\binom{K}2}$ as indicated in the first part of the answer to get $\frac2 K$, eg for a $16$ player tournament, it will be $\frac 2{16} = \frac1 8$